# Limiting characters in treeview nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, nodes

I have a file name `adobe-acrobat-xi-edit-text-and-images-in-a-pdf-file-tutorial-ue.pdf`
, is there a way to limit characters of a node of a treeview in asp.net programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wrap property along with fixing width . This will control the horizontal expansion of the tree because of name. As below.

```
TreeView1.Width = Unit.Parse("50");
TreeView1.NodeWrap = true;
```

Or You can loop throw each node to  take only fix number of characters. As below.

```
 foreach (TreeNode Node in TreeView1.Nodes)
        {
            Node.Text = new string(Node.Text.Take(5).ToArray());
        }
```

The above code will also work if the node text is of less than 5 char.